# What's the correct casing to use for jsDoc comments?

Tags: case-sensitive, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I've recently started using jsdoc comments for documenting our javascript code, however I'm finding conflicting examples of the usage of the @param tag.

See https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagParam (PascalCase)

and https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler (camel/lowercase).

camelCase makes sense to me since:

```
var foo = 1;
console.log(typeof foo); // outputs "number"
```

What's the correct casing to use for jsDoc @param comments? Or does it not matter? I'm planning to use it for document generation as well as running the code through google closure to get type checking.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The conflicting examples for JSDoc type expressions involve the JavaScript primitive types `string`, `number` and `boolean`, which have corresponding wrapper types: `String`, `Number`, and `Boolean`.

From [***Closure: The Definitive Guide***](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449381871):

> The use of wrapper types is prohibited in the [Closure Library](https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/), as
>   some functions may not behave correctly if wrapper types are used
>   where primitive types are expected.

See MDN: **[Distinction between string primitives and String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects)**.

Comment: In most cases, you want the primitive type rather than the Object type. The compiler will automatically box (promote) the primitive type when necessary, but the reverse isn't true.

Comment: Thanks cpeisert! I'll definitely have to get that book!

Comment: definitely do. It's a great read, not just for it's closure info!

Comment: What about 'function'?